# Get JSON keys in order

Tags: javascript, json

I have the below in a file and read as

```
var input = require("./mydata.json");

"User": {
        "properties": {
        "firstName": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1,
          "maxLength": 50
        },
        "lastName": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 50
        },
        "middleName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "language": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "en-US"
        }
      }
    }
```

I am using the below code to loop through the keys

```
var item = _.get(input, 'User');
var properties = item.properties;
var allKeys = _.keys(properties);
_.each(allKeys, function(key) {

});
```

Inside the each loop, I get the firstname, lastname etc, in the same sequence as in the input file.
I want to know if I will get it in order always?

Comment: I believe, you can't rely on that order. Hash table must not to preserve it. It's just lucky implementation.

Comment: Property order is a [complex subject](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/6445533) in Javascript

Answer (score 2):

Properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript; you need to use an `Array` to preserve it.

Definition of an Object from [ECMAScript Third Edition (pdf)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> #### 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the
>   type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which
>   contains a primitive value, object, or
>   function. A function stored in a
>   property of an object is called a
>   method.

**Since ECMAScript 2015**, using [the `Map` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) could be an alternative. A `Map` shares some similarities with an `Object` and [guarantees the keys order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared):

> A Map iterates its elements in insertion order, whereas iteration order is not specified for Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you want to change the order then you will need to sort or arrange the keys in a separate array and then loop on rearranged array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(input.User).sort();
// Will return all keys in sorted array.
```

Then , if you want to read value of each key **following that order** , just loop through that array :

```
Object.keys(input.User).sort().forEach((key,index)=>{

    console.log('key :'+key+' , value :'+input.User[key]);
})
```

Comment: I think the OP means the order they were defined, not some arbitrary order for the sake of it.